# My laptop keeps losing the HP Officejet 6500A through wifi. How can I prevent this?

Tags: wireless-networking, printer

My laptop is a Sony Vaio, and often, when I send files to print, it says the printer is offline, but I check the printer settings and it says it's connected and online.  This happens randomly and then I have to plug in the USB cable to print.  It's slightly annoying!

I have set a static IP address for my laptop. (I don't know if that's relevant, but thought I'd add it).

Comment: Exact operating system version? How do you check printer settings?

Comment: You should set a static ip to the printer also.  This sounds like a problem with the configuration of the printer, so contacting HP, sounds like your best option.